# 'TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined' when creating a function for a cart. This is the code snippet. What could be the issue?

Tags: reactjs

```
import useStyles from './styles';

const Cart = ({ cart }) => {
    const classes = useStyles();

    const isEmpty = !cart.line_items.length;

    const EmptyCart = () => (
        <Typography variant="subtitle1">There are no items in your cart</Typography>
    );
```

Comment: *"What could be the issue?"* - The issue is exactly what the error message tells you.  `cart.line_items` is `undefined`.  Where do you have information indicating otherwise?

Comment: from the browser console, line_items is the reference to the items in the cart. @David

Comment: Code in comments is unreadable.  If you have additional information to add to the question, please edit the question to include that information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined' says that you are trying to access the length property of a undefined value

So in your code

```
const isEmpty = !cart.line_items.length;
```

This is the line from which the error comes from. The `cart.line_items` value is undefined.
You can avoid this error by using the javascript chaining opertor ie. `const isEmpty = !cart.line_items?.length;`

This will check the length property of `cart.line_items` only if its having some value and not undefined.